# how to hide a select for internet explorer

Tags: javascript, select, hide, explorer

I have the next code:

```
<div id="divSpecies" style = "display:none">
    <select id="speciesListBox" multiple="multiple" name="speciesList"></select>
</div>
```

And this list box is hidden in chrome, safara and mozzila, but appears in explorer.How can i fix it?

Thaks!

Comment: ahhh hah... what phantom version of `IE` is this?

Comment: Do you need to keep the `select` in the DOM, or could you remove it (if you don't want it shown in IE)? Is it just IE you want to hide it from, or all browsers?

Comment: Since you have a javascript tag, is there any javascript in this page? Maybe some of it is messing with your visibilities. Otherwise, it's better to remove the tag.

Comment: it is explorer 8.0. I need it because it contains some usefull information.

Answer (score 0):

That's is very strange! Try visibility:hidden...

Or try to apply the style directly to the select tab, like:

```
<select id="speciesListBox" style="display:none;" multiple="multiple" name="speciesList"></select>
```

Comment: I tried 8 and 7 and it's OK (your own solution is fine). Probably, you could have something misplaced wrapping that code. Put your HTML and validate it http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input. See if there's some error that's causing the IE to not work properly...

Comment: Did you validate the code as I suggested above? If you get errors, please post them here.